# file_put_contents multiple image upload through API in PHP

Tags: php, api, file-upload

I am trying to upload multiple images through a PHP API.

When uploading, the data sending returns success, but it only uploads the names of the images to the Database and the files are not saved on the server side.

I tried to specify separate paths to decode, and then I used the `file_put_contents` function, but nothing uploads correctly to the server.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $pic = $_POST['pic'];
    $random = random_word(20);
    $path = "grocery/item_img/".$random.".jpg"; 
    $actualpath = "$random.jpg";
    $actualpath1 = "$random1.jpg";
    $actualpath2 = "$random2.jpg";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO item (`pic`, `pic1`, `pic2`) 
            VALUES (NULL, '$actualpath', '$actualpath1', '$actualpath2')";
    class emp{}
        if(mysqli_query($koneksi,$sql)){
foreach ($_POST['pic'] as $name) {
    file_put_contents($path, $name);
    }
        echo json_encode(array( 'success' => 1,'message'=>'Item Added Successfully')); 
    }
    else{
        echo json_encode(array( 'success' => 0,'message'=>'Failed to Add Item Image'));
    }
}
function random_word($id = 20){
    $pool = '1234567890abcdefghijkmnpqrstuvwxyz';
    $word = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $id; $i++){
        $word .= substr($pool, mt_rand(0, strlen($pool) -1), 1);
    }
    return $word;
```

Comment: Uploaded files are in `$_FILES`.

Comment: Read https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: am not uploading from a Form its through a mobile app image base64

Comment: You'll need to show how you're sending the image data from the app. Normally this would still be sent as a file upload.

Comment: If nothing is being put in the files, then the data probably isn't in `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

***SOLVED***

foreach gives Invalid argument supplied

when edits it to

```
  foreach ((array) $pic as $image)  {
...
}
```

error gone but still no uploads

then  tried

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"], $path1);
```

give error of :
Undefined index: pic
then edits to :

```
 if (isset($_FILES['foto'])) {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"], $path1); }
```

error gone but won't upload

tried to edit the file_put_contents
to the param of pic1
it uploaded the second pic ,,,

so below is the working code which uploads the three images while storing their paths to the DB

anyway to make it neat while working

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
  
    $pic = $_POST['pic'];
    $pic1 = $_POST['pic1'];
    $pic2 = $_POST['pic2'];
    $random = random_word(20);
    $random1 = random_word(20);
    $random2 = random_word(20);
    $path = "../item_img/".$random.".jpg";
    $actualpath = "$random.jpg";
    $actualpath1 = "$random1.jpg";
    $actualpath2 = "$random2.jpg";



    //upload files

    $path1 = '../item_img/'.$actualpath;
    $path2 = '../item_img/'.$actualpath1;
    $path3 = '../item_img/'.$actualpath2;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO item (`pic`, `pic1`, `pic2`) 
            VALUES (NULL, '$actualpath', '$actualpath1', '$actualpath2')";
    class emp{}
        if(mysqli_query($koneksi,$sql)){
         file_put_contents($path1,base64_decode($pic));
         file_put_contents($path2,base64_decode($pic1));
         file_put_contents($path3,base64_decode($pic2));
    }
        echo json_encode(array( 'success' => 1,'message'=>'Item Added Successfully')); 
    }
    else{
        echo json_encode(array( 'success' => 0,'message'=>'Failed to Add Item Image'));
    }
}
function random_word($id = 20){
    $pool = '1234567890abcdefghijkmnpqrstuvwxyz';
    $word = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $id; $i++){
        $word .= substr($pool, mt_rand(0, strlen($pool) -1), 1);
    }
    return $word;
```